# All observations dropped after converting variable type SAS

Tags: sas

I have two data sets that I'm merging (called "trends" and "insurance") and both have similar variables. One such similar variable is "Race", except in the "trends" dataset, Excel has coded it as a character variable, and in the "insurance" dataset, Excel coded it as numeric. Of course I can't merge these two variables if they aren't the same type, and I tried changing the type to numeric in Excel under the "Format" option. It didn't appear to work. Once I re-imported my XLS file in SAS, it continued to say "Race" was character, not numeric.

So I tried to do the conversion in SAS, like this:

```
DATA trends;
new = input(Race, 8.);
drop Race;
RENAME new = Race;
RUN;
```

Here's the output.

```
NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places   
given by:
(Line):(Column).
66:13
NOTE: Variable Race is uninitialized.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TRENDS has 1 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

But what I ended up with when I PROC CONTENTS DATA = trends; is NO observations at all in the new dataset. There should be over 800 observations and over 20 variables, just as there is when I originally import the XLS file into SAS.

Here is what the output of PROC CONTENTS looks like after converting "Race" to numeric:

```
Obs Race 
1   .
```

What happened to all my observations and other variables? Basically, the entire dataset "trends" is missing now.

Comment: In addition to the error I point out, you should know that there are probably better ways to handle this (via modifying your import statement and/or importing in a different way).  Excel is not necessarily at fault here (as Excel mostly doesn't have "types"); it's more likely the input conversion.  Feel free to ask a separate question about that, or simply browse for questions about setting type on import.

Answer (score 1):

```
DATA trends;
new = input(Race, 8.);
drop Race;
RENAME new = Race;
RUN;
```

Where is SAS getting the input data for `race` from?  You need a `set` statement to get it from an already existing dataset, or `input` and `infile` to get it from a text file.

In this case it sounds like it should be:

```
DATA trends;
  set trends;
  new = input(Race, 8.);
  drop Race;
  RENAME new = Race;
RUN;
```

Though I always recommend a different name to the new dataset, as you can't rerun this step if you were to find some mistake.  `data trends_racenum; set trends;...` would be good for example (to show it has the numeric race in it).

Comment: Thanks, but I did as you suggested and all that did is make SAS return a mountain of errors. I'm so frustrated with trying to manipulate data that comes from Excel. All I ever get is problem after problem. I'm thinking about exporting my spreadsheets into MS Access instead, then importing into SAS. Maybe that will help solve the problem.

Comment: Certainly that sometimes does help solve the problem.  If you're using Enterprise Guide, you could also use the Import File Task wizard; that would allow you to select the column types proactively.  Unfortunately, Excel is a very poor database, but is often used for that purpose.